# How do you trace/debug Apache Camel or AOP-modified code?

Tags: java, debugging, aop, trace, apache-camel

I'm trying to debug a webapp using Apache Camel from Eclipse and while I'm 'tracing into' I arrive at a point where Eclipse says that no source file is available and I can see bytecode shown in Eclipse (where usually I see sourcecode) but apparently I cannot advance into that bytecode (I try 'F6 / Step Over' but nothing happens) anyway (not that it would have been that useful compared to source code).

So how are you supposed to trace into such a beast?

I'm wondering if all these code-generating/code-intercepting layers aren't creating more problems than they're trying to solve.  It seems like it's helpful as long as everything works but as soon as there's a problem, things become very hard to diagnose.

**EDIT** I don't want to trace Apache Camel *itself*.  I just want to trace a program that is using Apache Camel and I realize that things quickly gets very messy: basically you kinda lose your tracing ability because you jump from your Java source code to "something".

Comment: What is the class for which you get this message?

Comment: Apache Camel is open source.  Get the source and attach it to the library in Eclipse, and you'll be able to debug into it and see source.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Camel does not do any bytecode manipulator or instrumentation. At most it uses the Proxy from the JDK library if you use the Camel Proxy feature.

So it must be other libraries which causes your eclipse debugger not being able to step into the source code.

All the source code for Apache Camel is distributed as -source JARs using the maven standard.
If you use maven there is a maven command to download the -source JARs which I assume Eclipse is then capable of using.

I am not using Eclipse, but use IDEA which has can auto download the -source JARs from the maven repos.

Answer (score 1):

To debug code proxed by CGlib or JDK Proxy navigate your debugger to the line that calls proxed code...

```
public void foo() {
  serviceWithProxy.bar(); // put breakpoint here
}
```

...now before you step into `serviceWithProxy.bar()` press `Ctrl+T` (Eclipse) and select type you want to debug (for example `ServiceWithProxyImpl`). Put the breakpoint in the first line of `ServiceWithProxyImpl#bar` (Eclipse navigates you there automatically) and press "Continue" in debugger. This is the simplest way to skip proxy while debugging.